# Create a looped variable in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to create a loop in R with a string `mod` and a variable `x`

my code so far looks like this `m=1` and `b=1` at the start of the code

```
  for (i in 1:5){
  mod = 'mod'
  mod + as.character(m) = b
  m = as.numeric(m)
  m = m+1
  b = (b + 1) * 2
}
```

what I want as an output is:

```
mod1 = 1
mod2 = 4
mod3 = 10
```

Is this possible or am I overthinking this problem?

Comment: Your output, is it just text? Or you want to have mod1, mod2, mod3 objects with values 1,4,10 assigned to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign values to a variable with incrementing id using `assign(paste("mod",m,sep=""), b)`

Your loop could be something like this:

```
for (i in 1:5){
  assign(paste("mod",m,sep=""), b)
  m = m+1
  b = (b + 1) * 2
}
```

You can find these variables in memory, as the loop is closed:

```
> mod1
[1] 1
> mod2
[1] 4
> mod3
[1] 10
> mod4
[1] 22
> mod5
[1] 46
> mod6
[1] 94
```

Comment: that is what i was missing. the paste option within the assign. I've tried that assign first, that didn't work and after swiched to my code above. Thx @Terru_theTerror

Answer (score 0):

Save the results in a list, use `list2env`

```
m=1
b=1

res=list()

for (i in 1:5){
  mod = 'mod'
  res[[paste0(mod,as.character(m))]] = b
  m = as.numeric(m)
  m = m+1
  b = (b + 1) * 2
}

list2env(res,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```